# How to compile W-9 form if I live in Italy?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I have a US and Italian citizen and I live in Italy and pay taxes here.
Recently I worked for a US company as a freelancer providing a website update.
I sent them the invoice under my name but they are asking me to compile the the **W-9 form**.
**I compiled the W-9 form this way:**
*- Name*
- CHECKED *Individual/sole proprietor

- Adress

- Social Security Number*

- Signed.

Should I compile that form?

Do I have to pay tax in Italy and in US for that job?

Comment: As a US citizen, you need to file a tax return every year --- regardless of where you live.  As a US citizen living abroad, you may have a  reasonable [foreign earned income exclusion](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-earned-income-exclusion) which means you don't pay tax on the first USD ~100k of your foreign income. But you still need to file.

Answer (score 2):

answer to: should i compile the W9 form -
Yes. You need to fill W9 form as you are identified as US person. This form is for reporting your incomes against your tax identification number.

answer to : pay taxes in US and Italy
This is a duplicate question. please see below story.

Great answer: If a US citizen works in Europe as a consultant, what are the tax consequences?
https://money.stackexchange.com/a/8421/55816